# AngularDart dynamically change the page title

Tags: dart, angular-dart

One of my components pulls a page title (and content) from MongoDB based off of the route and stores the title in an instance variable of that component's class. What would be the best way to give some mustaches in the `<title>` tag a variable to display such as `<title>Site Title | {{pageName}}</title>`? The `<title>` tag is outside of the scope of the component. Maybe a controller would fit this use case but I'm not really sure what the state of the controller directive or the root object is. I thought about making a service and injecting it in both but that seems like overkill. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up making a new component and a service.

My simplified `index.html` (Pretty much no changes):

```dart
<html ng-app>
    <title>Site Title</title>
</head>
<body></body>
```

Service to store one variable:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Injectable()
class Global {
  String pageTitle;

  Global();
}
```

And component with a selector of title:

```dart
library title;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:mypackage/service/global.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'title',
    template: 'Site Title | {{titleComp.global.pageTitle}}',
    publishAs: 'titleComp',
    useShadowDom: false)
class TitleComponent {
  final Global global;

  TitleComponent(this.global);
}
```

I then injected Global into another component and modified `global.pageTitle` whenever a new page was loaded.

I would love to hear any improvements to this or ways to use a root controller or root scope.

Comment: Yup. I've just never used a controller and am not really sure when they should be used...

Comment: As far as I know (didn't work with Angular for a while) controllers are about to become extinct - in the end only one controller should exist - the `rootContent`. I don't know if a currently released version already supports this. A controller is similar to a component without a template. The rootContext would allow you to use binding like your `{{titleComp.global.pageTitle}}` outside of a component (for example directly in the `body`).

Comment: I've seem some of the issues for the Controller is Context milestone. So I guess just wait till that has some more progress before trying to use them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain this is not possible -- I don't think angular is able to do any interpolation outside the body tag.  Your best bet is to use the [Document.title()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.HtmlDocument#id_title=) method.

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem. You can put the `ng-app` attribute on the `<html ng-app>`. It doesn't make sense for some tags/attributes in the header because the `{{}}` are only evaluated and assigned to after Angular was initialized but I don't know how he can do the binding when the `{{}}` isn't in the scope of the component that holds the values. He could create a service that holds the title value and provide access to this service in the root controller.
In the component he can access the service to change the value.

Comment: How would you use the root controller? If this is documented somewhere, a link to it would be enough. I also know it is changing a lot so I'm not sure what currently is valid documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
<title ng-bind="header"></title>
```

And then inside your Controller

```
testController = function($scope, $rootScope) {
   $scope.someFunction = function() {
      $rootScope.header = "Test";
   }
}
```